# Changing date excel cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date cells which contain the date format with the general. I want to change its cell with the same format like other cells but the problem is if I change it then it will change the entirely format of its cell.

What I've tried so far is within this formula inside of its formatting cells

```
(mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss)
```

But I all I want to is just using the same format like the others. Thanks

Check on the file please try to change the value and any helps will be so much helpful

https://hotfile.com/dl/157148115/5ee7808/datesample.xlsx.html

Answer (score 0):

The dates are stored as text
You can use `datevalue` and `timevalue` to convert the data to a real date format
in A2, enter `=DATEVALUE(A1)+TIMEVALUE(A1)` to get a value you can format as you wish

```
"05/02/2012 16:23:53"   41031.68325
"05/02/2012 16:23:53"   41031.68325
"05/04/2012 08:17:52"   41033.34574
```

the value displayed in the 2nd column is the excel representation of a date/time - you can then format these how you want, or do calculations to get durations.

Comment: Can you post the date that you've changed? Thank you

Comment: I edited my answer to add in the data you gave from your example spreadsheet. I put the formula into A2, and copied it down. I deliberately did not format the cells, so you can see what excel returns.